# Prove or disprove that if f is continuous on a bounded set S, then f is bounded function on S

Tags: continuity

Prove or disprove that if f is continuous on a bounded set S.
Then f is bounded function on S.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you, say, give some simple examples of bounded sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f: x\mapsto \ln (x) $$ is continuous at $(0,1] $ but
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln (x )=-\infty $$

thus $f $ is unbounded at $(0,1] $.

Comment: Can I ask a proof for this question? I could understand in uniformly continuous situation, but I can't prove this question...